# Best way to join list with DbSet Under Different Circumstances

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

maybe this is a duplicate but basically I want to know what is the best way to join a in memory list/ienumerable to a dbset under different circumstances.

The circumstances are:

1. List/Ienumerable is small, dbset is small
2. List/Ienumerable is small, dbset is big
3. List/Ienumerable is big, dbset is small
4. List/Ienumerable is big, dbset is big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you let the database management system do the join, you'll have to send the complete local list to the DBMS.

If you want to let your process do the join, you'll have to fetch the complete table.

There are two methods to make this more efficient:

- Only transport the properties that will be used to create the result
- Only transport records of which you are certain that they match the join predicate (the keys match)

To do this, send only the keys on which you want to join your local source to the database, and ask only for records with a Key that is in my local set of keys:

```
IEnumerable<int> localIDs = ...
var fetchedItems = dbContext.MyDbSet
    .Where(item => localIds.Contains(item.Id)
    .Select(item => new
    {
         Id = item.Id
         ... // select the foreign data that you will use in the result.
    });
```

Once you've fetched the foreign data, you can execute the join locally. This way you have transported no more data than you actually use.

The problem is in **Contains**. This will be translated into something like:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

The values are the IDs that you send to the DBMS. The larger your list the more values you need to send. There is a maximum of values you can use this way. I expect that this maximum depends on the quality of your DBMS. The limit is usually more than 1000 items.

Let's create an extensionmethod to join the two tables. See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
IEnumerable<TResult> Join<TForeign, TLocal, TKey, TForeignResult, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<Tforeign> databaseSource,
    IEnumerable<Tlocal> localSource,

    Expression<Func<Tforeign, TKey> foreignKeySelector,
    Func<Tlocal, TKey> localKeySelector,

    Expression<Func<TForeign, TForeignResult> foreignResultSelector,

    Func<TLocal, TForeignResult, TResult> resultSelector)
{
```

This looks similar to the normal Join. Except that I have an extra ResultSelector: this selector makes sure that you only transfer the foreign properties that you actually use to compose a TResult.

```
    // Extract all Ids from local and fetch the records with matching IDs
    IEnumerable<TKey> localKeys = localSource.Select(localKeySelector).Distinct;

    // get all records from the database that have a key that is in localKeys
    // from these records select only the properties in foreignResultSelector
    var fetchedData = databaseSource
        .Select(foreignItem => new
        {
            Key = foreignKeySelector(foreignItem),
            ForeignResult = foreignResultSelector(foreignItem),
        })

        // keep only the foreign items with a key that is in localKeys:
        .Where(foreignItem => localKeys.Contains(foreignItem.Key);
```

Ok, so now we have a query to transport only those records that will be used in the join: there are no records without a matching Key from localSource. Only the properties that you want to use in your end result are transported.

Now all we have to do is transport the data to local process and join it with localSource:

```
    .AsEnumerable()         // Transport to local process
    .Join(localSource,
        foreignItem => foreignItem.Key,
        localItem => localKeySelector(localItem),

        // ResultSelector: get the foreign data and the local item to create a TResult
        (foreignItem, localItem) => ResultSelector(localTime, foreignItem.ForeignResult));
    }
}
```

Although the transport of data is optimized, the local source is enumerated twice: once to extract the IDs, and once to join. If you look at [reference source for Enumerable.Join](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,b7b87afe6c3fc715) you can see that the join is executed using a LookupTable.

Instead of extracting the IDs, create a LookupTable: key is the Id, Values are the local source items that match this ID:

```
ILookup<TKey, TLocal> localLookup = localSource
    .ToLookup(localItem => localKeySelector(localItem);
IEnumerable<TKey> idsToFetch = localLookup.Select(item => item.Key);

// same query as above.
var fetchedData = ...
```

After the data is fetched, get the key of every fetched Item and get all matching local elements from the lookup. Use these to create a TResult:

```
foreach(var fetchedItem in fetchedData)
{
    TKey foreignKey = fetchedItem.Key;
    TForeignResult foreignResult = fetchedItem.ForeignResult;
    IEnumerable<TSource> matchingLocalItems = localLookup[foreignKey];

    foreach (TSource localItem in matchingLocalItems)
    {
        TResult result = ResultSelector(localItem, foreignResult);
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the very detailed feedback! Definitely more detailed than what i was expecting, appreciate it!